# Is there any harm in using both analytics.js and ga.js scripts on website?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I work at a large company that uses a lot of tracking across various websites. We are trying to track the user source and other details in the cookies, which isn't tracked by the current script we have added to the website (analytics.js). These details are tracked by ga.js, but I know that is a legacy script that isn't usually recommended.

I was wondering if I added ga.js to the website in addition to analytics.js, could it could mess up any of the tracking being done with analytics.js? There are multiple teams doing tracking and I don't want the scripts to conflict. Or if anyone has any suggestions on how to track the source in the cookies with analytics.js that would be super helpful!